# BLDC ESC contoller

Tags: arduino, transistors, power

[image]

I saw a youtube video which powers bldc using arduino. Just a safety precaution because I will be powering the BLDC, can the 3 blue wires be interchanged because the 3 blue wires are all of the same color and does not label red, yellow or black to be plugged into the BLDC motor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The blue wires from the ESC can be hooked up to the motor in any order and it will work. If the motor spins the wrong direction, swap any 2 wires.